# Do proteins move inside the cell?

Tags: proteins

Do proteins move inside the cell and how fast do they move or move? Please support your answer with articles or books.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because while it may be vaguely related to biology, it isn't related to bioinformatics.

Answer (score 2):

Proteins move in cells or get transported in the cell. You can go to NCBI (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/), and start searching for protein dynamics within cells. Also there is a technique called FRAP (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescence_recovery_after_photobleaching) which is used to measure kinetics and dynamics.
Also, this differs probably a lot between the cellular system you are asking for. You can imagine that some cells have a more active transport system because stretched out (neurons) vs others with maybe less active transport systems, because of a more static nature.